# Gulp stopped working and says 'paths is not defined'

Tags: node.js, gulp, bower

I am fairly new to gulp but had it working nicely.
Came back to it after a couple of days and it's showing errors.
I also now have to sudo npm install where I didnt need to before, and some step I did has caused my main js file to require password to save. Could this be the source of the errors?

Here is the error message:

```
ReferenceError: paths is not defined
at Object. (/Applications/AMPPS/www/site/wp-content/themes/myproject/gulpfile.js:34:75)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
at Liftoff. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:198:16)
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:17:3)
```

Gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var bower = require('gulp-bower')
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files')
// var path = require('path')

var sass = require('gulp-sass')
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer')
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin')
// var minifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss') // Minifies CSS files

var sass = require('gulp-sass'); // Gulp pluign for Sass compilation
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'); // Autoprefixing magic

// JS related plugins.
var concat = require('gulp-concat'); // Concatenates JS files
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify'); // Minifies JS files

// Utility related plugins.
var rename = require('gulp-rename'); // Renames files E.g. style.css -> style.min.css
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'); // Maps code in a compressed file (E.g. style.css) back to it’s original position in a source file (E.g. structure.scss, which was later combined with other css files to generate style.css)
var notify = require('gulp-notify'); // Sends message notification to you
var pump = require('pump');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

// Tasks

gulp.task('bower', function() {
return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*.min.js'), { base: 'bower_components' })
.pipe(gulp.dest('library/js/libs'))
});

var buildVendors = gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*.min.js')).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.buildBower));
return gulp.src(paths.index)
.pipe(inject(buildBowerFiles,{
relative: true,
name: 'bowerInject'
}));

var config = {
srcCss : 'library/scss/**/*.scss',
buildCss: 'library/css',
buildJs: 'library/js',
}

gulp.task('build-css', function(cb) {
gulp.src(config.srcCss)

  // output non-minified CSS file
  .pipe(sass({
     outputStyle : 'expanded'
  }).on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(autoprefixer())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildCss))

  // output the minified version
  .pipe(cssmin())
  .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('library/css'));

cb()
})

gulp.task('build-js', function () {
gulp.src('library/js/scripts.js')
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
.pipe(gulp.dest('library/js'))
})

gulp.task('watch', function(cb) {
gulp.watch(config.srcCss, ['build-css'])
gulp.watch(config.buildJs, ['build-js']);
})

gulp.task('default', ['build-css', 'build-js', 'watch'])
```

What version of gulp are you using?

[22:10:02] CLI version 3.9.1
[22:10:02] Local version 3.9.1

What versions of npm and node are you using?
npm 2.12.0
node v0.12.0

Comment: For now I commented out the 'buildVendors' section which is what is causing the error. If I find a fix I will post it here

Comment: `paths` is referenced in few places in the file and it's not defined anywhere, so the error is pretty self-explanatory. As for `sudo` and requiring password; it seems to be a directory permissions issue.

Comment: I see that now. I had copied and pasted the 'buildVendors' code, originally had a paths variable defined, but then opted for the simpler 4 lines of code above and removed the paths. I uncommented buildVendors for some reason and came back to the project after a couple of days.

The error threw me a bit, but I now see it even points to line 34

Comment: Also have a much better understanding now of conventions for vendor (plugins) scripts which can be concatenated, minified etc for production. I will probably end up rewriting that part.

I also managed to reset the permissions on my js file so everything is working smoothly again. Guess I should check more closely before posting!
Anyway, some of that gulpfile might be useful for someone..